# Is the sentence "You wouldn't know if he did" grammatical/idiomatic?

Tags: ellipsis, subjunctives, past-vs-past-perfect

Google gives you [0 results](https://www.google.com/search?q="you+wouldn't+know+if+he+did") so I'm a bit skeptic.

Example sentence:

> Speaker A: "My husband has never lied to me."
>
> Speaker B: “You wouldn’t know if he did.”

(Meaning that Speaker A wouldn't know her husband was lying even if he lied to her. Because he wouldn't have told her.)

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The complement of the auxiliary verb "did" is ellipted, but understood as "Lie to you". This is perfectly normal in such constructions

Comment: The two alternatives are *You wouldn't know if he **did** [lie to you **at any time** in the past, present, or future]* and *You wouldn't know if he **had** [lied to you **in the past**]*. Which in principle do mean slightly different things.

Comment: There are trillions upon trillions of possible English sentences, and it is easy to make a new one that no one has ever spoken before, so it's not surprising that you can't find any results for one particular sentence.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, but I for one am very surprised indeed. The sentence only involves function words (auxiliaries and pronouns) apart from the verb *know*. It's like getting no results for "He didn't know it".

Comment: Try instead googling "you would know if you did".  2.5 million results.

Comment: How about "You wouldn't know **it** if he did"? In this sentence, I take "if he did" to be the direct object of "You wouldn't know," anticipated by dummy "it." The original sentence without "it" could sound like a conditional, which it is not.

Comment: It's very common and you can find plenty of attestations. For example, https://books.google.com/books?id=w1y9cXLrkyQC&pg=PA58&dq=%22not+know+if+he+did%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik0vv6mPLSAhUE44MKHfi3AfYQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=%22not%20know%20if%20he%20did%22&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other folks should get points, but they answered in the Comments.

It is grammatically incorrect.  To agree with the tense of the sentence, it should be, "You wouldn't know if he had".

Idiomatically, if you want to refer to the previous history, then I would say, "If he had, you wouldn't know it".  If you want to talk about the on-going history of his truthfulness, I would say, "If he did, you wouldn't know it".

Answer (score 0):

It's true that "had" would tie more closely to the verb in the initial sentence, but "did" would be acceptable if the speaker wanted to indicate that the action might not have already happened. It would also be acceptable in speech to cover either meaning.